# Помогите с запятыми

Tags: пунктуация

Пожалуйста, объясните постановку запятых: "Я говорю о оболочке, в которой копятся, а затем, заставляют человека страдать, переживания".

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Тут не только запятые проблемные, но ещё и предлог.

*Я говорю о**б** оболочке, в которой копятся, а затем заставляют человека страдать переживания.*

С предлогом правило простое - "б" добавляется, когда слово в предложном падеже начинается с гласного звука.

С запятыми сложнее - они в приведённом предложении немотивированные. Если очень хочется понизить интонацию, убрать "перечислительную", можно использовать скобки:

*Я говорю о**б** оболочке, в которой копятся (а затем заставляют человека страдать) переживания.*

Answer (score 2):

Обособленный оборот со значением **присоединения (выделяет значимую для автора часть в отдельную конструкцию):** Я говорю об оболочке, в которой копятся, **а затем заставляют человека страдать**, переживания.

Другие варианты

1) **Нейтральный вариант**, запятая между однородными сказуемыми, союзный формант А ЗАТЕМ: Я говорю об оболочке, в которой переживания **копятся, а затем заставляют** человека **страдать.**

2) Вариант с деепричастием: Я говорю об оболочке, в которой копятся, **заставляя затем человека страдать**,  переживания.